# useformik and yup error message is displayed only once

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am using `useformik` hook on my page along with yup to display validations. I have a custom component using `formik` values and has a validation definition on yup `validationSchema`. the error message is displaying only once either on **Tab** or **submit**.

```
 const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({   
        message: yup
      .string()
      .when(["category"], {
        is: (category) =>
          category !== CATEGORY_CANDIDATE_EMAIL.toString(),
        then: yup
          .string()
          .matches(/RELATED.LINK/, "the RELATED.LINK text is required" ),
      })
      .required("error message required message")
      .nullable()
      .trim(),
    category: yup
      .string()
      .required("error message required category")
      .nullable()
      .trim(),   
  });
```

```
<CustomInput
            id="message"
            name="message"
            value={formik.values.message}
            bodyText={messageTextLocalized}
            readonly={false}
            previewModeError={false}
            placeHolderText={msgEnterEmailTemplatemessageTextLocalized}
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleChange({ target: { name: "message", value: e } });
              setCustomValidation({
                ...customValidation,
                message:
                  e.indexOf("RELATED.LINK") === -1 &&
                  formik.values.category !==
                    `${CATEGORY_CANDIDATE_EMAIL}`,
              });
            }}
            hasError={
              customValidation.message ||
              ((formik.errors.message && formik.touched.message) as boolean)
            }
            errorMessage={formik.errors.message || ""}
          />
```

I tried to add another `<ErrorMessage />` field to display but it is now displaying same error message twice. can anyone please help me identify what can be done here.

Comment: does the new field have a different id name?

Comment: no @JamieGarcia. the Id and name is "message". the yup validation schema seems to be working fine updating the errorMessage based on the category field selected. But the error message displays only once which means when I enter a text with out the RELATED.LINK text it displays the error message but when I type "text RELATED" it does not show the error message and submit action process through